# Applying foreach in gridview rows doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, gridview, foreach, row

I have a gridview and i am converting gridview rows to a datatable... But i cant able to get the value of a hiddenfield in cell[0] inside the gridview....

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmpId", typeof(Int64)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FromDate", typeof(DateTime)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ToDate", typeof(DateTime)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DaysPresent", typeof(decimal)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("OpeningAdvance", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AdvanceDeducted", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RemainingAdvance", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SalaryGiven", typeof(double)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CreatedDate", typeof(DateTime)));

    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridEmployee.Rows) 
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["EmpId"] = Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[0].Text);
        dr["FromDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(GetMonthNumberFromAbbreviation(fromdate[1].ToString()) + '/' + fromdate[0].ToString() + '/' + fromdate[2].ToString());
        dr["ToDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(GetMonthNumberFromAbbreviation(todate[1].ToString()) + '/' + todate[0].ToString() + '/' + todate[2].ToString());
        dr["DaysPresent"] = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[4].Text);
        dr["OpeningAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[5].Text);
        dr["AdvanceDeducted"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[6].Text);
        dr["RemainingAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[7].Text);
        dr["SalaryGiven"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[8].Text);
        dr["CreatedDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

I got the error in the line,

`dr["EmpId"] = Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[0].Text);`

`Input String was not in a correct format`

**Note:**

`Cells[0]` is a hiddenfield which contains EmpId....

```
 <asp:TemplateField >
   <HeaderStyle Width="1%" />
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenId" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("Emp_Id") %>' />
     <asp:Label ID="LblHiddenId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Emp_Id") %>'></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <ItemStyle Width="1%" CssClass="GridCs" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

My gridview,
[image]

Comment: For `CreatedDate`, you can just write `dr["CreatedDate"] = DateTime.Now`.

Comment: @Slaks ok ... But i cant get the hidden field value... But when i used a label instead i got the value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a conditional to make sure you're not parsing the header and the footer:

EDIT: Working result (leaving the other one because it may also apply to similar situations

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridEmployee.Rows) 
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["EmpId"] = Convert.ToInt64(((Label)cells[0].FindControl("LblHiddenId")).Text);
    dr["FromDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(GetMonthNumberFromAbbreviation(fromdate[1].ToString()) + '/' + fromdate[0].ToString() + '/' + fromdate[2].ToString());
    dr["ToDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(GetMonthNumberFromAbbreviation(todate[1].ToString()) + '/' + todate[0].ToString() + '/' + todate[2].ToString());
    dr["DaysPresent"] = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[4].Text);
    dr["OpeningAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[5].Text);
    dr["AdvanceDeducted"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[6].Text);
    dr["RemainingAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[7].Text);
    dr["SalaryGiven"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[8].Text);
    dr["CreatedDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

EDIT: Since I don't have studio on this to correct myself

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gridEmployee.Rows) 
{
    if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["EmpId"] = Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells[0].Text);
        dr["FromDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(GetMonthNumberFromAbbreviation(fromdate[1].ToString()) + '/' + fromdate[0].ToString() + '/' + fromdate[2].ToString());
        dr["ToDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(GetMonthNumberFromAbbreviation(todate[1].ToString()) + '/' + todate[0].ToString() + '/' + todate[2].ToString());
        dr["DaysPresent"] = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[4].Text);
        dr["OpeningAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[5].Text);
        dr["AdvanceDeducted"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[6].Text);
        dr["RemainingAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[7].Text);
        dr["SalaryGiven"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[8].Text);
        dr["CreatedDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}
```

Comment: @joel look at my image i am looping through my gridview rows in a button click and not in a gridview event...

Comment: @Pandiya: that was just a paste from an event online. Let me edit for your EXACT example.

Comment: @Pandiya: Is this just a boundfield like the others with the attribute Visible="False"?

Comment: @Pandiya: Try ((Label)cells[0].FindControl("LblHiddenId")).Text

Comment: @joel everything works fine until `dr["RemainingAdvance"] = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[7].Text);` I calculating this textbox value using javascript....

Comment: @Pandiya: If you're storing it in a textbox you'll need to use the findcontrol method again. I'm not sure this will work though because the JavaScript won't edit the control itself in ViewState. You may be able to access the textbox's value by using its name and going through HttpContext.Current.Request[txtBoxName].

Answer (score 2):

This error means that `cells[0].Text` doesn't contain a number.

Check the value of `row.Cells[0].Text` in the debugger.